# HowTo JavaScript ES modules dynamic import with rollup.js?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, es6-modules, rollupjs

I try to use [JS ES modules with a fallback bundle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules#browser), generated by rollup.js.

Standard `import`s are no problem. But I have an issue with dynamic imports.

I uploaded the full example of the setup here:
https://www.file-upload.net/download-13588759/gulp-setup-example.zip.html

Run:
1. `yarn install`
2. `gulp test`

The setup of the `gulpfile.babel.js` is:

```js
import buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';
import gulp from 'gulp';
import loadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import rollup from 'rollup-stream';
import rollupPluginBabel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';

const $_ = loadPlugins();

/*
 * JavaScript
 */
function processJavaScriptMain() {
  return rollup({
    input: 'src/main.mjs',
    format: 'es',
    sourcemap: true,
    plugins: [
      rollupPluginBabel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      }),
    ],
  })
  .pipe(source('main.mjs', 'src')) // Bundle name
  .pipe(buffer())
  .pipe($_.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
  //.pipe($_.terser())
  .pipe($_.rename('main.bundle.js'))
  .pipe($_.sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
}

gulp.task('test', processJavaScriptMain);
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

And the file `main.js` is the entry point for the bundle and contains:

```js
import {demoUtil2} from './modules/utils.mjs';

// Work
console.log('demoUtil', demoUtil2());

// 1. example: Doesn't work
(async () => {
  const someCondition = true;
  if (someCondition) {
    const Demo = await import('./modules/Demo.mjs');
    new Demo();
  }
})();

// -----

// 2. example: Doesn't work ether
const someCondition  = true;
if (someCondition ) {
  import('./modules/Demo.mjs').then(({ default: DefaultExport, NamedExport })=> {
    console.log('hit');
  });
}
```

The documentation from rollup.js says [that dynamic imports should be possible](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#dynamic-import).

In the code from above the *1. example* result in the error:

```
Error: Unexpected token
    at error (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:185:14)
    at Module.error (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:8170:3)
    at tryParse (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:7888:10)
    at new Module (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:7924:15)
    at load.catch.then.then.then.source (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:9749:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

The second example (like in the rollup.js docs) result in the error:

```
Error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
    at error (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:185:14)
    at Module.error (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:8170:3)
    at tryParse (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:7888:10)
    at new Module (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:7924:15)
    at load.catch.then.then.then.source (C:\Users\user\Desktop\example\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:9749:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

I expected, that the content of the dynamic imports is in some kind inline within the bundle or something like extracted into a different bundle.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: check the rollup.js version and the acorn parser version in its dependencies?

Comment: Try updating rollup commonJs `Error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level` -> this fixed my issues and presented a whole set of other issues